# dotnet core build in parallel or simultaneously

Tags: node.js, powershell, .net-core, dotnet-cli

In [this](https://github.com/gatimus/DotnetParallelBuild) solution I have 2 apps: `AppA`, `AppB` that share class library `Shared`. I have tried automating the build/running of these in parallel with both a [PowerShell](https://github.com/gatimus/DotnetParallelBuild/blob/master/build.ps1) and [node](https://github.com/gatimus/DotnetParallelBuild/blob/master/build-script/app.js) scripts (I'd be open to other solutions). I'm using both `--no-dependencies` and `--no-restore` flags, but intermittently I get:

```
'CSC : error CS2012: Cannot open \'C:\\Users\\User\\source\\repos\\ParallelBuild\\Shared\\obj\\Debug\\netcoreapp2.0\\Shared.dll\' for writing -- \'The process cannot access the file \'C:\\Users\\User\\source\\repos\\ParallelBuild\\Shared\\obj\\Debug\\netcoreapp2.0\\Shared.dll\' because it is being used by another process.\' [C:\\Users\\User\\source\\repos\\ParallelBuild\\Shared\\Shared.csproj]\r\n'
```

PowerShell:
./build.ps1
[image]

node:
run project `build-script` or `node ./build-script/app.js`
[image]

Why is the `Shared` project building even with the `--no-dependencies` flag? How do I build in parallel or simultaneously?

Comment: How are you calling the build process? Post your code.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 all of the code is in the repo

Comment: Didn't notice the links, thanks

Comment: I could reproduce your issue. But it happens rarely. It works 9 nine time and then it fails. Using Process Monitor v3.40 I observed the processes, which access shared.dll and I can see that during build shared.dll is read by both build processes. This is necessary in order to read meta information from it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Explanation for error CS2012 :The process cannot access the file**

I could reproduce your issue and [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) indicates that both processes open `shared.dll` at the same time for reading. This leads to the issue you described.

Although reading the same file from different processes can be done by using `FileShare.Read` as the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.fileshare(v=vs.110).aspx) indicates (see excerpt below), it seems that this is **NOT** done by `csc.exe`. This is a shortcoming of `csc.exe`, which probably won't be changed in the near future.

> Allows subsequent opening of the file for reading. If this flag is not
>   specified, any request to open the file for reading (by this process
>   or another process) will fail until the file is closed. However, even
>   if this flag is specified, additional permissions might still be
>   needed to access the file.

**Solution**

Instead of using `Start-Process` to achieve parallel building, you could use msbuild, which supports this out of the box.

Parallel build is supported by msbuild with `/maxcpucount`-switch and `BuildInParallel`-task parameter as described in [MS build documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb651793.aspx).

Parallel build is enabled by using `/maxcpucount`-switch on commandline:

> dotnet msbuild .\ParallelBuildAB.csproj /target:build /restore:false
>   /maxcpucount:2

In addition it is also necessary to use `BuildInParallel`-task Parameter in project-file ParallelBuildAB.csproj. Please note that `AppA.csproj` and `AppB.csproj` are referenced:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Project name="system" default="build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="build">
        <MSBuild BuildInParallel="true" Projects="./AppA/AppA.csproj;./AppB/AppB.csproj" Targets="Build"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: So I have to make new project `ParallelBuildAB.csproj` to build the 2 projects in parallel? Also is is possible to run them from the same command?